# Exposing a Room database to other apps

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Android Architectural components introduced new concept to store application data locally: [Room.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)

Previously using a `ContentProvider` we can expose a database to other applications. How to we do the same with Room?

Comment: https://medium.com/@aniket93shetty/content-provider-for-sharing-room-database-using-kotlin-c196ca1d8471

Answer (score 7):

> How to expose database to other apps when we create database using Room?

The most likely answer: use a `ContentProvider`. The biggest difference is that you will use your `RoomDatabase` and its `getOpenHelper()` method, rather than working with `SQLiteOpenHelper` yourself. You would use the same sort of methods for queries, inserts, updates, and deletes as before, though `SupportSQLiteDatabase` has a slightly different API than does `SQLiteDatabase`.

There is nothing stopping you from having your `ContentProvider` use `@Dao` methods to get objects back, but then you have to turn around and convert them back into `Cursor` objects (in the case of `query()`), and this may be tedious.

As with non-Room databases, you are also welcome to expose Room databases through any other IPC mechanism that suits your needs, such as a bound service with an AIDL-defined interface. Room has no direct relationship with those IPC mechanisms, but neither does `SQLiteDatabase`.

Answer (score 5):

To expose a database to other apps you still need `ContentProvider`. But, with help of `Room`, you may access the data in your database easier in your provider application.

**A snippet on ContentProvider that work with Room.**

you can do like @lomza answer, but I suggest to use @CommonsWare answer. since it gives the client more flexibility to query the data (if your business say so otherwise, you can go query with @Dao)

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection,
                    @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    final int code = MATCHER.match(uri);

    if (code == CODE_CHEESE_DIR) {
        final Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(Cheese.TABLE_NAME);
        String query = builder.buildQuery(projection, selection, null, null, sortOrder, null);

        final Cursor cursor = SampleDatabase.getInstance(context)
                .getOpenHelper()
                .getWritableDatabase()
                .query(query, selectionArgs);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
}
```

And let say you have DAO like this.

```
@Dao
public interface ChesseDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Chesse.TABLE_NAME)
    LiveData<Cheese> read();

}
```

So, you in the application you can access data with `Room` or `ContentProvider` is up to you.

**A snippet on Access data via ContentProvider directly.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ... someview setup...

    // test
    LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(1, null, mLoaderCallbacks);
}

private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {

        String[] projections = new String[] {
                Chesse.COLUMN_ID
                Cheese.COLUMN_NAME
        };

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            return new CursorLoader(
                    YourActivity.this,
                    SampleContentProvider.URI_CHEESE,
                    projections,
                    null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String chesseName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Cheese.COLUMN_NAME));
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, chesseName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        }
    };
```

**A snippet on Access data via Room**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... someview setup...

    // test
    SampleDatabase.getInstance(this).chesse().read().observe(this, chesse -> {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, chesse.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the dao-generated `@Query("SELECT * FROM *") Cursor selectAll();` cursor? What exactly are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

Check the code of [Room with Content Providers Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample) on GitHub. There isn't much magic around using Room with ContentProvider. For instance, insert() looks like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
    switch (MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case CODE_CHEESE_DIR:
            final Context context = getContext();
            if (context == null) {
                return null;
            }
            final long id = SampleDatabase.getInstance(context).cheese()
                    .insert(Cheese.fromContentValues(values));
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
        case CODE_CHEESE_ITEM:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI, cannot insert with ID: " + uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi refer https://medium.com/@aniket93shetty/content-provider-for-sharing-room-database-using-kotlin-c196ca1d8471